# Linux kernel hangs when attempting to dual boot Elementary OS on 2018 Mac

Tags: macos, kernel-panic, dual-boot

I am attempting to dual boot Elementary OS from a live USB on my 2018 Catalina MacBook Pro. After shutting down my Mac, I plug in the USB drive and start up the computer, while holding down the option key. After a few seconds, the Elementary OS logo appears, and a few seconds later I get a slew of errors, including the following message: `ICM Firmware is in wrong mode: 15`.

I have disabled SIP and Secure boot (as I have a newer Mac with the T2 chips), and can't figure out what the issue is.

Here is an image of the error messages:

[image: Error image]

Comment: [This post](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/intel-linux/976737-clear-linux-adding-kernel-modules) may set you on the right track.

Comment: [This page](https://aroman.github.io/elementary-on-a-mac/) written in Dec 2016 indicates compatibility issues with more recent Macs.  I would imagine this is the case with your 2018 as well.